# What is the complexity of the "characteristic bisection" method?

Tags: time-complexity, na.numerical-analysis, paper-review

The *characteristic bisection method* is an algorithm for finding approximate zeros of multi-dimensional functions. It is a generalization of the bisection method; it is described briefly [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method#Characteristic_bisection_method).

Apparently, the method first appeared in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389620) by Vrahatis and Iordanidis. In Lemma 4.7 in that paper, the authors prove that the number of iterations required for an $\epsilon$-approximation is *at least* $\lceil \log_2(\Delta/\varepsilon) \rceil$, where $\Delta$ is the diameter of the initial polyhedron. The proof also seems to prove only a lower bound - since there are iterations in which the polyhedron does not change at all.

However, in later papers, such as [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-40616-5_17) by Vrahatis, it is claimed (in Theorem 5) that the number of required iterations is *exactly*  $\lceil \log_2(\Delta/\varepsilon) \rceil$.

I did not find a proof of an upper bound, but maybe it is there and I just missed it. QUESTION: what is the actual run-time complexity of this "characteristic bisection" method?